# Eclipse cannot find twitter class

Tags: eclipse, twitter, jar, twitter4j

I downloaded twitter4j-core-3.0.3-sources.jar and put under my project's lib folder.I did this step :  project->Build Path-> ConfigureBuildPath->Add jar ... But now my project cannot find twitter class, I cannot import twitter.Status . I can import twitter.*;

Comment: I try Add External Jar File and it is ok now!

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded the sources file, which is full of .java files that Eclipse will use when you want to see the library's classes' source code.

In order for Eclipse to use the classes, you'll have to add the binary .jar to your build path (and remove the *-source.jar one). You can then link the binary .jar to the -source.jar to be able to navigate to the library classes' definitions.

Comment: I try to import jar file using Add External Jar File. And it is ok. Thank you for your advice.